# Generating an array of numbers based off the smallest numbers in other arrays?

Tags: c#

How do I go about making an array of numbers based off of the lowest values generated in other arrays? I have made an array that generates numbers between -1000 and 1000 and calculates the the lowest number from that; my problem comes after that I believe. I cant figure out how to add the lowest value to the "lowestNumbers" array.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //ints and arrays used in the program.
        int min = -1000;
        int max = 1000;
        int currentMinimum = 1000;
        int[] numbers = new int[10];
        int[] lowestNumbers = new int[numbers.Length];
        Random rndm = new Random();

        //Using a loop to create random numbers within numbers array between -1000 and 1000.
        for (int i = 0; i < lowestNumbers.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i < lowestNumbers.Length)
            {
                for (int index = 0; index < numbers.Length; index++)
                {
                    if (index < numbers.Length)
                    {
                        numbers[index] = rndm.Next(min, max);
                    }
                }

                for (int index = 0; index < numbers.Length; index++)
                {
                    if (numbers[index] < currentMinimum)
                        currentMinimum = numbers[index];
                }
            }
            lowestNumbers[i] = currentMinimum;
        }

        foreach (int value in lowestNumbers)
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        Console.WriteLine("//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `var lowest = numbers.Min();`

Comment: `var secondSetOfNumbers = firstSetOfNumbers.OrderBy(n=>n).Take(100).ToArray();`

Comment: Also, remember that `maxValue` on [`Random.Next`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx) is *exclusive*, so that in your code, `1000` will never be in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Use the power of Linq:

```
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(_ => rndm.Next(min, max)).ToArray();
var lowest = numbers.Min();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based off the answer of @Laoujin, but slightly expanded a bit.

This will generate 1000 integers, from -1000 to 1000, and give you an array of the 100 lowest.  I added `1` to `max` in the call to [`Random.Next(Int32, Int32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx) since `maxValue` is *exclusive*, otherwise the number `1000` would never show up in the resulting array.

```
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).Select(_ => rndm.Next(min, max+1)).ToArray();
var lowest = numbers.OrderBy(n => n).Take(100).ToArray();
```

---

As an extra note, if you are confused about the `_` in the first line (many people are, the first time they see it used this way), that is just commonly used to denote an unused argument in a lambda expression.  In this case, that variable contains the current number generated from [`Enumerable.Range()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.110).aspx) via the [`Select()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) call, but since it isn't being used, it is just named `_`.  This isn't enforced by the language in any way, it is a common pattern that lots of programmers use.

---

That might contain duplicates though, so if you don't want them, you can pass the list though [`IEnumerable.Distinct()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx) first, which returns only unique items:

```
var lowest = numbers.Distinct().OrderBy(n => n).Take(100).ToArray();
```

If you want the absolute lowest number from the first array, you can just do:

```
var lowestNumber = numbers.Min();
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up figuring out a way to get int working without using this but now i'm going about trying to learn it this way.

Comment: If you want to learn more about this way of doing things, it is called LINQ (language integrated query).